# Can i lock the xampp folder with a password?

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I am using a small warehouse manager, which runs on my laptops

> localhost `php` server

. Recently someone deleted a file from it from my laptop.. I have two worker. They accidentally deleted a file from xampp htdocs folder.. So i want to lock the xamp folder.. Is it possible.. If not how can i serve pages to other system from my server installed on my laptop.. Just suggest me where to find relevant info or in which direction i shold go now..

Comment: Did they delete it from windows or from the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are a lot of tools for Windows (free & commercial):

- Folder Protector
- LocK-A-FoLdeR
- etc.

See here: http://www.7tutorials.com/5-tools-password-protect-your-folders-windows.

If you're using Windows 8.1 watch the following video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1X0mOW9y2iw